# Gostaria de saber como carregar os dados de um HTML em Outro

Tags: php, html, crud

Preciso carregar em um novo HTML os dados fornecidos pelo primeiro (HTML) para realizar a alteração.A proposta da atividade que estou em dúvida é a seguinte:

"assim que o cadastro do cliente for realizado, deverá ser exibido um link para a página de alteração dos dados do cliente que acabou de ser inserido."

A tela de Cadastro funciona mas preciso de saber como carregar os dados na nova página de alteração.

Comment: A primeira página html deve ter no "action" do form uma página em php que irá guardar os dados no banco. Essa página em php deve chamar outra com o link para uma outra que irá pegar os dados do banco e exibí-los. Você deve estudar html, php e gravação e leitura em banco de dados para fazer isso. Dê uma olhada no site w3schools.com lá tem muita coisa bacana para aprender.

Answer (score 0):

Thomaz,

Provavelmente o seu primeiro HTML de cadastro salvou os dados em um banco de dados, certo?

Ao exibir a segunda página, de alteração, você deverá:

1. Pegar os dados previamente cadastrados do banco de dados (com PDO, funções mysqli_* ou algum ORM)
2. Colocar estes valores no seu formulário HTML, como por exemplo:

   ```
   <input type="text" name="nome_usuario" value="<?=$usuario['nome']?>" />
   ```
3. E realizar a ação de alterar do novo do novo formulário.

Se você quiser usar o mesmo formulário HTML tanto na página de cadastro quanto na página de edição você precisa cuidar de três coisas:

1. Mudar o action do form se for edição ou cadastro:

```
<form action=""<?=$urlCadastrarOuAlterar?>"
```

2. Nos valores dos campos, terá que verificar se existe usuário:

```
<input type="text" name="nome_usuario" value="<?=isset($usuario) ? $usuario['nome'] : ''?>" />
```

3. No caso da edição, salvar o id do usuário em um campo hidden.